# Overnight connection in Guangzhou - where do I sleep?

Tags: accommodation, australian-citizens, china-southern-airlines, guangzhou, can

I've found a cheap flight from Korea to Australia with China Southern Airlines but it involves a 15-hour connection in Guangzhou, overnight.

I'm pretty sure that as an Australian I need a visa and that there's no visa on arrival at this airport.

But then again I've had a few flights on other airlines which included an overnight stay in a hotel operated by the airline, even on fairly cheap tickets.

So where should I expect to be able to sleep during my night in Guangzhou?

Comment: Check the reviews here: http://www.sleepinginairports.net/asia/guangzhou.htm this site is for info on where to sleep in airports!

Comment: So it looks like sleeping in the airport is one option, but nobody mentioned whether there's free WIFI or not.

Comment: @hippietrail wifi is many places and it is very likely to have free wifi, at worse it will be at one of the coffee shops; you will be in the international terminal, so WI-FI will be more likely.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand of the laws is this:

Visas are not required for aliens in immediate transit on connected international flights who hold passenger tickets and stay for no more than 24 hours in China entirely within airport boundaries. Anyone desiring to leave the airport temporarily must obtain permission from the frontier inspection office. If you want to stay in a hotel near the airport (there are many hotels near the airport), you need the permission from the frontier inspection office.

Now do realize this is China, and enforcement of the laws can vary; however, I wouldn't try to book a hotel room, because you have to be registered with the police, so I would contact the airline and see what they can do for you.

Comment: I'm in a similar situation, but I have a Chinese visa and I'm leaving the country, with a stop in Guangzhou, also with China Southern Airlines. Am I allowed to leave the airport in Guangzhou?